# Truncate the amount of truncation tags so they are truncated (truncat[e|ion|ed])

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

We seem to have a lot of tags that are nearly the same:

[truncate](/questions/tagged/truncate) - 505 questions
[truncation](/questions/tagged/truncation) - 95 questions
[truncated](/questions/tagged/truncated) - 52 questions

These tags should be merged.

Comment: s/merged/truncated/ :p

Comment: Truncate the truncation tags!

Comment: I think they should be burned, I don't see any purpose in them.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby At least one should stay IMO - truncating is a common task when programming...

Comment: @Doorknob: Yes, but do we need tags for common tasks? Can it stand on it's own?

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby Yes, it can stand on **its** own. For example: Question: "How do I truncate certain words based on criteria that the user defines?" or something of the like.

Comment: @Doorknob: Damn it...I fall for that every single time. Also, I'm not sure if that example qualifies as good question. I did look through some of the questions, and the term "truncate" is used for *everything*, starting by file truncation, over a textbox truncating the input, forward to string truncation, to truncation of doubles when converted to singles right to image resizing and random sampling...it's a very broad tag to start with.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby That is a good point... maybe they should just all be burninated and replace with [file-truncation], [string-truncation], etc.

Comment: @Doorknob: I'm still not entirely sure about those tags, but that would be *vast* improvement over the current situation. At this amount of questions, manual cleanup is even possible.